# How to change texture of highlighted object in unity 3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a problem: how do I change part of the texture of an object which is highlighted, but only partially in the light, not all of it. Can I do this in Unity ?

Comment: Yes, this is probably possible with shaders. You'll have to devise a solution with your own research and attempts though, before coming to Stack Overflow - as it stands, your question is too broad for the site. Take a look at [this Unity question](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/381183/two-textures-on-one-surface.html) for some ideas of what you can try.

Comment: Thank, you. I am not good in unity and 3D now. I will lern this.